# cannot load <img> to <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing as simple image gallery.

This is what I got for now

```
function init(){
  var elem = document.createElement("img");

  elem.scr='upload/creative-design-modern-furniture.jpg';
  elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
  elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
  elem.setAttribute("alt", "furniture");

  document.getElementById("imagegal").appendChild(elem);
}

<body onload='init();'>
<div id="imagegal" ></div>
```

Now, I know this is easy, but I dont get any errors in the console. 
I see a white square with the word "furniture" inside (the alt text). I dont see the image.

The folder "upload" that contains all the images is inside the file that contains the script files (apache/htdocs/myproject/upload)

The images get uploaded by the user using website's interface. In the "upload" file, all the thumbs of the images have a little golden padlock on the side. What is that? What symbolizes? I dont know

Any help/tips?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Yes , it was a typo. Thanks guys. I guess I deserve the down votes

But, anyway, whats with the golden padlock on the side of every thumbnail?

Thanks again

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh my God, you are right, I'm so sorry. My native language is Greek, so that was my mistake. I meant folder. I'll edit right now

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo in your code:

```
elem.src='upload/creative-design-modern-furniture.jpg';
  //  ^---- was 'scr' in your code
```

Comment: 5 sec makes difference ohhh  :P

Answer (score 1):

You have made typo

```
elem.scr='upload/creative-design-modern-furniture.jpg';
```

should be

```
elem.src='upload/creative-design-modern-furniture.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably made a typo, using scr="..." instead of src="....".

I highly suggest that you use some element inspectors in browsers such as firebug (Mozilla Firefox), DragonFly (Opera) or Chrome built-in tool to check how the code is finally formed in the page when loaded and easily locate those types of errors. They are easy to use, they allow you to test and make such modifications in html/js/css on-the-fly and they can save you **a lot of time**.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when you're setting the source. Instead of `elem.scr` it should be `elem.src`.